# Configuring application directories using ConfigurationManager - where to start?

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config, configurationmanager

The desktop application I am developing. should store its output files in some determined folders.

I have heard that this could be configured in `App.config` file, but I didn't quite understood how to do it.

1. My application doesn't seem to have such file. How should I create it?
2. How should I specifically define "special application folders"? These would be specifically named subdirectories living in the same folder of the main application executable, is that right? Could/should they be elsewhere in the client PC filesystem? For example, it's possible that our company decides to release a suite of applications, using the same common folders in the client machine;
3. How should I "read" these folders in code, so that I can perform file IO operations in them?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

To add an app.config file, in the VS Add new item dialog, select Application Configuration File.

Once you've got the file, create a class in your project that inherits from `ConfigurationSection`, say `MyProjectConfigurationSection`, insert a section in the app.config that can be deserialized to your class and use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` to read from the file at runtime and deserialise it into your configuration class.

Include the paths to your special folders in the configuration section that is shipped with your software.